# No. of hops to a website using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, networking

Is it possible to count the number of hops to a website using javascript (in browser javascript) ?

where hop count : the number of hops a packet has taken toward its destination.

if no ? what are the other options that i have ?

Comment: Please be more specific with your desired output.  Are you talking about emulating the output of traceroute?

Comment: yeah kind of from the chrome browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As several people have already mentioned, there is no *pure* javascript way to do this.

However, if you really want this type of functionality on a webpage, you could simply use javascript to load a server side page (perhaps through AJAX), and use a server side programming language to do all the heavy lifting

An example server side language, could be PERL, as there is a ['traceroute' library](http://www.linnaean.org/~hag/perl/traceroute/Traceroute.pm.html). The library page also has an example to get you started

Comment: but then the server side language will count the number of hops from the server not the client/browser.

Comment: Yes, and as per *every* single comment on this page, there is no pure client side technology that will solve your problem. I was merely pointing out that a combination of client and server side programming languages can solve your issue, and would be super easy involving < 50 lines of code ;)

Answer (score 2):

**No.**

Well, technically I guess one could use an ActiveX control with JavaScript.... but... no.

**Edit:** I assumed you meant in-browser JS. If it's server-side JS then the same applies: "technically" if you have access to the appropriate library/program/API with such low-level network access. But, generally (and insofar as JavaScript itself) no.